# Asp.net vNext Cookie Authentication

Tags: asp.net, cookies, asp.net-core

Our website needs to authenticate against a third party webservice and create a cookie.  We don't need to store the membership information. I have the following code in Startup.cs

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options => {
            options.AuthenticationScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.LoginPath = new PathString("/User/Login");
            options.CookieName = "GEMSNCID";
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = new System.TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
        });
```

and the login method is

```
var claims = new[] 
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, model.UserName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Country, "USA")
            };
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);  
            ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            Context.Response.SignIn(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

This is not working. Can someone please help.

Comment: What version of the package are you using? if you can see the options.AutomaticAuthentication property, you should be setting that to true.

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean by "not working".

Comment: It works with options.AutomaticAuthentication = true as @Suhas Joshi described!

Answer (score 0):

I think something change on the new beta 4 version. I will try this code is working on my my sample application

```
var claims = new[] 
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, model.UserName),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Country, "USA")
};
var user = this.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
var identity = user.Identities.Where(x => x.AuthenticationType == CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).FirstOrDefault();

if (identity == null)
{
    identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims.ToArray(), CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    user.AddIdentity(identity);
}
else
    identity.AddClaims(claims);

if (this.Context.Response.HttpContext.User.Claims.Count() > 1)
    this.Context.Response.SignIn(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
```